# Adding Data to multiple tables with a single form, in the form there are multiple file inputs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, mariadb, save

Hello stackoverflow please help me. I am trying to insert a from post on db, I do have two tables posts and tags tables. When I insert the create the post I want to be able to insert the data from the form in those two different tables.

controller.php;

```
public function save(Request $request){
    if($this->user != '' || $this->userlong != ''){
        $request->validate([
            'fileNmOriFoto' => 'required',
            'fileNmOriFoto.*' => 'mimes:doc,docx,PDF,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
            'fileNmOriKTP' => 'required',
            'fileNmOriKTP.*' => 'mimes:doc,docx,PDF,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
            'fileNmOriBukti' => 'required',
            'fileNmOriBukti.*' => 'mimes:doc,docx,PDF,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
            'fileNmOriDenah' => 'required',
            'fileNmOriDenah' => 'mimes:doc,docx,PDF,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
            'fileNmOriKuasa' => '',
            'fileNmOriKuasa' => 'mimes:doc,docx,PDF,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
            'fileNmOriLain' => '',
            'fileNmOriLain' => 'mimes:doc,docx,PDF,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png|max:2000',
            'krkNoUrut' => 'required',
            'krkNama' => 'required',
            'krkTglLahir' => 'required',
            'krkNoHP' => 'required',
            'krkPekerjaan' => 'required',
            'krkAlamat' => 'required',
            'krkNamaTanah' => 'required',
            'krkLuasTanah' => 'required',
            'krkNomorPersil' => 'required',
            'krkTanahKel' => 'required',
            'krkTanahKec' => 'required',
            'krkTanahKab' => 'required',
            'krkTanahProv' => 'required',
            'krkStatusTanah' => 'required',
            'krkRencanaFor' => 'required'
        ]);

        $krk = new Krk();
        $krk->krkNoUrut = $request->input('krkNoUrut');
        $krk->krkNama = $request->input('krkNama');
        $krk->krkTglLahir = $request->input('krkTglLahir');
        $krk->krkNoHP = $request->input('krkNoHP');
        $krk->krkPekerjaan = $request->input('krkPekerjaan');
        $krk->krkAlamat = $request->input('krkAlamat');
        $krk->krkNamaTanah = $request->input('krkNamaTanah');
        $krk->krkLuasTanah = $request->input('krkLuasTanah');
        $krk->krkNomorPersil = $request->input('krkNomorPersil');
        $krk->krkTanahKel = $request->input('krkTanahKel');
        $krk->krkTanahKec = $request->input('krkTanahKec');
        $krk->krkTanahKab = $request->input('krkTanahKab');
        $krk->krkTanahProv = $request->input('krkTanahProv');
        $krk->krkStatusTanah = $request->input('krkStatusTanah');
        $krk->krkRencanaFor = $request->input('krkRencanaFor');
        $krk->save();

        $krkId = Krk::select('krkId')->orderby('krkId', 'desc')->first();
 
        if ($request->hasfile('fileNmOriFoto')) { 
            $files = [];
            foreach ($request->file('fileNmOriFoto') as $file) {
                if ($file->isValid()) {
                    $fileNmOriFoto = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$file->getClientOriginalName());
                    $file->move(public_path('images'), $fileNmOriFoto);                    
                    $files[] = [
                        'fileNmOriFoto' => $fileNmOriFoto,
                        'fileKd' => $krkId->krkId,
                    ];
                }
            }
            Krkfile::insert($files);            
            echo'Success';
        }if($request->hasfile('fileNmOriKTP')){
            $files2 = [];
            foreach ($request->file('fileNmOriKTP') as $file2) {
                if ($file2->isValid()) {
                    $fileNmOriKTP = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$file2->getClientOriginalName());
                    $file2->move(public_path('images'), $fileNmOriKTP);                    
                    $files2[] = [
                        'fileNmOriKTP' => $fileNmOriKTP,
                        'fileKd' => $krkId->krkId,
                    ];
                }
            }
            Krkfile::insert($files2);            
            echo'Success';
        }if($request->hasfile('fileNmOriBukti')){
            $files3 = [];
            foreach ($request->file('fileNmOriBukti') as $file3) {
                if ($file3->isValid()) {
                    $fileNmOriBukti = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$file3->getClientOriginalName());
                    $file3->move(public_path('images'), $fileNmOriBukti);                    
                    $files3[] = [
                        'fileNmOriBukti' => $fileNmOriBukti,
                        'fileKd' => $krkId->krkId,
                    ];
                }
            }
            Krkfile::insert($files3);            
            echo'Success';
        }if($request->hasfile('fileNmOriBukti')){
            $files4 = [];
            foreach ($request->file('fileNmOriBukti') as $file4) {
                if ($file4->isValid()) {
                    $fileNmOriBukti = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$file4->getClientOriginalName());
                    $file4->move(public_path('images'), $fileNmOriBukti);                    
                    $files4[] = [
                        'fileNmOriBukti' => $fileNmOriBukti,
                        'fileKd' => $krkId->krkId,
                    ];
                }
            }
            Krkfile::insert($files4);            
            echo'Success';
        }if($request->hasfile('fileNmOriDenah')){
            $files5 = [];
            foreach ($request->file('fileNmOriDenah') as $file5) {
                if ($file5->isValid()) {
                    $fileNmOriDenah = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$file5->getClientOriginalName());
                    $file5->move(public_path('images'), $fileNmOriDenah);                    
                    $files5[] = [
                        'fileNmOriDenah' => $fileNmOriDenah,
                        'fileKd' => $krkId->krkId,
                    ];
                }
            }
            Krkfile::insert($files5);            
            echo'Success';
        }if($request->hasfile('fileNmOriKuasa')){
            $files6 = [];
            foreach ($request->file('fileNmOriKuasa') as $file6) {
                if ($file6->isValid()) {
                    $fileNmOriKuasa = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$file6->getClientOriginalName());
                    $file6->move(public_path('images'), $fileNmOriKuasa);                    
                    $files6[] = [
                        'fileNmOriKuasa' => $fileNmOriKuasa,
                        'fileKd' => $krkId->krkId,
                    ];
                }
            }
            Krkfile::insert($files6);            
            echo'Success';
        }if($request->hasfile('fileNmOriLain')){
            $files7 = [];
            foreach ($request->file('fileNmOriLain') as $file7) {
                if ($file7->isValid()) {
                    $fileNmOriLain = round(microtime(true) * 1000).'-'.str_replace(' ','-',$file7->getClientOriginalName());
                    $file7->move(public_path('images'), $fileNmOriLain);                    
                    $files7[] = [
                        'fileNmOriLain' => $fileNmOriLain,
                        'fileKd' => $krkId->krkId,
                    ];
                }
            }
            Krkfile::insert($files7);            
            echo'Success';
        }else{
            echo'Gagal';
        }
    }else{
        $wallidx = rand(1, 7);
        $data = array(
            'wallidx' => $wallidx,
            'message' => 'Session Habis',
        );
    }
}
```

i get error "Type error: Too few arguments to function Krk\AdmkrkController::save(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE9sJ.png)

please help me to fix it.

(edited)
this is my route

> Route::post('admsavekrk','Krk\AdmkrkController@save');

I save it using the post method on the form.

Comment: Why don't you make helper function or method to get rid of duplicate code of saving images?

Comment: Regarding the question, show us how you r calling `save` method, if it is called by laravel you shouldn't have that error